# How fast is it to bruteforce a 48-bit key with current technology?

Tags: brute-force, entropy, key

Say you have a truly random hexadecimal key formatted as 1234.5678.ABCD, with 48-bit entropy. Assuming the key is stored with no hashing/salting, how fast/easy would it be to brute force it with **current** hardware? I'm interested in 2 different scenarios:

- Attacker with $1000 budget
- Attacker with $1M budget

Bonus points if you can provide sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A day, instantly.**

48 bits are not an awful lot, also merely *generating* (which per se does not make a lot of sense) that many keys is very fast.
Even a naive single-threaded CPU implementation on a cheapish (not even remotely close to $1000) desktop computer could do that in a day or two.

In order to be meaningful, you must do something with these keys to verify them. It is explicitly mentioned "no hashing/salting" in the question, so one can safely assume that no expensive key derivation (think beecrypt or such) which artificially slows us down needs to be done.
I will therefore assume that you need to decrypt a block of AES and compare the result to a known plaintext.

[This article](http://www.naun.org/main/UPress/ami/20-242.pdf) claimed 11Gbps on a CUDA implementation 6 years ago, which would boil down to about 4 days for brute-forcing your 48-bit key. Assume that a rig with a current upper middleclass or high-class GPU is 3-5 times as fast, and we are at approximately **one day** for your $1000 budget (give or take a few hours, it makes no difference).

A $1M budget attacker could naively just do that same attack with 1000 machines, which would require a minuscule amount of communication between nodes (add some milliseconds) and place him at around 1 1/2 minutes, give or take a few secs.

If you however assume that an attacker with such a budget is serious about the attack, you must assume that something better is used. A HPC cluster comes to mind as the next naive solution, but why not invest in FPGAs?
If you are serious, you can *easily* get 10 or 100 times as fast than the "simply use 1000 desktop computers" solution for the same money.
Let's just *assume* 100 times faster, and we're at 0.9 seconds. Why assume? Well, because it no longer makes a difference at this point.

Practically, it doesn't matter at all whether an attack takes 9 seconds, 0.9 seconds, or 0.00009 seconds. They all fall under **instantly**. Anything you can crack in 9 seconds is doomed.

Comment: So, beecrypt is like bcrypt but [uses bees](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33680/991)? ​ ^_^ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yep, I just love bees. They're busy things working from dawn to dusk, too, which would actually make sense for the name, as well. And bumblebees, of course! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given that 48 bits have 2.81475e14 combinations, and that you can generate a few billion a second, it should not take more than a day. A day = 86400 seconds.

Comment: He did not specify what he needs the key for.